# Oracle database connection via Codeingniter 4

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Hi I have a Oracle database installed locally on my laptop. I'd like to connect to it via Codeigniter 4. Since version 4.2.0 it is able to do so.

https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/changelogs/v4.2.0.html

All my database credentials are in the .env file, but I'm unable to establish connection. I'm new to Oracle.

I can connect to my database via Oracle SQL Developer.
The data I use for the connection:

- host: localhost
- port: 1521
- user: system
- password: MYPASSWORD
- service name: orcl

How can I use that in my .env file?

This is what I have so far:

```
 database.default.hostname = localhost
 database.default.database =
 database.default.username = system
 database.default.password = MYPASSWORD
 database.default.DBDriver = oci8
 database.default.DBPrefix =
 database.default.port = 1521
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to connect to the database.
Main connection [oci8]: oci_connect(): ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(`.env` file)*
Try using:

```bash
 database.default.hostname = '127.0.0.1:1521/orcl'
```

Where:

```
'127.0.0.1:1521/orcl', // hostname:db_port/service_name
```